# CanCan - "user" parameter is nil - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, rails-admin

I am using Rails 4.0.1 and ruby 2.1.1. I am trying to integrate cancan with rails_admin. My `application_controller.rb` looks like this

```
helper_method :current_user

private

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(email: session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

My `current_user` helper method is working fine from rest of the application. My `ability.rb` looks like this

```
class Ablity
  include CanCan::Ability

   def initialize(user)
     if user
       can :access, :rails_admin
     end
   end
end
```

Control is not going inside the if condition at all, which means the "user" parameter is "nil". When I try to access rails_admin I get a `CanCan::AccessDenied` exception. Where am I going wrong?

**Edit** : I am not using devise for authentication

**Update** : I've replaced `cancan` with `cancancan` version 1.8. Still not working

Comment: are you using devise for authentication?

Comment: Nope. My authentication depends on `REST` calls. So I use my own customized authentication.

Comment: Try defining your current_user method under `protected` rather than `private`

Comment: `cancan` is not compatible with Rails 4 and is no longer maintained. Use `cancancan` instead: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan.

Comment: I've used it with my rails 4 application

Comment: Well I'm here to tell you the gem is no longer maintained, and doesn't work properly with `strong_parameters`. Have you tried to replace it with `cancancan` (continuation of same gem, actively maintained)? Regardless, you shouldn't be using dormant gems, who knows what security holes will be left unpatched as new versions of Rails are released.

Comment: @RSB - I tried changing it to `protected`. Still now working

Comment: @DamienRoche - I've replaced it with `cancancan`. Sorry I forgot to mention. So should I change my rails_admin config too? Like

    config.authorize_with :cancancan

Comment: I can't say I've used `cancancan` with `rails_admin`. Just wanted to rule that out, and be sure you were running with latest updates.

Comment: I ran `bundle update` and `bundle install` and my `Gemfile` entry is `gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.8'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved. In `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` we have to specify the `current_user_method` as

```
config.current_user_method { current_user } # refers to the current_user helper method in my case
```

Now everything is working perfectly. I am surprised why this isn't specified anywhere in the documentation.